# Permission denied on git operations while working via ssh

Tags: git, ssh, vpn

Backstory: I am working on a Windows PC that is connected to a Ubuntu laptop via SSH. This laptop is connected to the company network via VPN. Company uses gitea (if that's relevant).

The problem: While attempting to use git from PC (Windows Terminal, VS Code terminal, VS Code git features) I am getting a `Permission denied (publickey)` message. Everything works fine if I'm trying to do the same from a terminal on the laptop.
Similarly, `pipenv install` fails on installing dependencies from the repository.

Visualization :)
`[Laptop]: git pull` results in a successful pull
`[PC --ssh-> Laptop]: git pull` results in a permission denied

No such things happen when I try to access my private github repos with PC ssh'd to my other computer.
I have even tried adding a key generated on PC to the authorized git keys with no improvement whatsoever.

EDIT: [@VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68843743/14175591) made me run a verbose `ssh` connection and revealed that ssh-agent wasn't running for my remote connection and only offered keys from `~/.ssh/` that started with `id_` while my git key had a `git_` prefix.

Comment: Sounds like you do not have a SSH key on your PC that is registered with the git server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test first, from a simple CMD:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

That will display the path ofthe keys SSH will try to use.

Check for instance if you do have  a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa` key, with its [`.pub` content registered to your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

Note on my own company laptop, connected by VPN, I would not be able to perform an Egress SSH operation: SSH is disabled for [egress](https://www.fortinet.com/resources/cyberglossary/data-egress).

As the [OP seseikelele](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14175591/seseikelele) notes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68829764/permission-denied-on-git-operations-while-working-via-ssh/68843743#comment121671514_68843743):

> Running verbose SSH to the git server revealed that shell sessions from my PC didn't use keys provided by ssh-agent and just tried to offer keys wih `id_` prefix.
>
> **Starting the agent** allowed Git to get authenticated on that one shell instance.

Comment: Running verbose SSH to the git server revealed that shell sessions from my PC didn't use keys provided by ssh-agent and just tried to offer keys wih `id_` prefix.
Starting the agent allowed git to get authenticated on that one shell instance.

Comment: @seseikelele Welldone, good catch. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.